# Dataset of number of car accidents per cause in the United States

Tags: data-request, usa, cars

I am looking for a dataset that lists the number of car accidents broken down by causes in the United States. By cause I mean the direct cause of the accident such as failure to stop at red light, or changing lane without checking for the blind spot. (not the indirect cause such a driving under the influence). Ideally, broken down by year as well.

---

The [Wikipedia page on Epidemiology of motor vehicle collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemiology_of_motor_vehicle_collisions) contains a list by type of crashes (not cause):

> Crashes are categorized by what is struck and the direction of impact,
>   or impacts. These are some common crash types, based on the total
>   number that occurred in the U.S.A. in 2005, the percentage of total
>   crashes, and the percentage of fatal crashes:
>
> - Rear impacts (1,824,000 crashes, 29.6% of all US crashes, 5.4% of US fatal crashes)
> - Angle or side impacts (1,779,000 crashes, 28.9% of all US crashes, 20.7% of US fatal crashes)
> - Run-off-road collisions (992,000 crashes, 16.1% of US crashes, 31.7% of US fatal crashes)
> - Collisions with animals (275,000 crashes, 4.5% of US crashes, 0.4% of fatal crashes)
> - Rollovers (141,000 crashes, 2.3% of all US crashes, 10.9% of US fatal crashes)
> - Head-on collision (123,000 crashes, only 2.0% of all US crashes, but 10.1% of US fatal crashes)
> - Collisions with pedestrians and bicyclists (114,000 crashes, only 1.8% of US crashes, but 13.5% of US fatal crashes)
> - Back-up collisions killed 221 people in the US in 2007, and injured about 14,400. This is one of the most common types of non-traffic auto
>     collision in which road workers and children 15 and younger are
>     killed.

Answer (score 2):

The NHTSA has a survey with reasons for crashes.

> Table 1. Driver, Vehicle, and Environment Related Critical Reasons
>
> Table 2. Driver‐Related Critical Reasons
>
> Table 3. Vehicle‐Related Critical Reasons
>
> Table 4. Environment‐Related Critical Reasons

https://crashstats.nhtsa.dot.gov/Api/Public/ViewPublication/812506  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180429182103/https://crashstats.nhtsa.dot.gov/Api/Public/ViewPublication/812506))