# Is there a data set for all vehicle accidents in USA?

Tags: data-request, usa, government

Looking for raw data of road traffic accidents, with impact location, make, model, model year, airbag deployment (Y/N)

Comment: FYI [Dataset of number of car accidents per cause in the United States](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6823/1652)

Answer (score 4):

The DOT keeps track of every *fatal* traffic accident since 1975 in their FARS database. They host all their data on [their FTP](ftp://ftp.nhtsa.dot.gov/fars/2015/), but I've also collected their data since 2001 in a format that's easier to work with [here](https://numeracy.co/sirwart/traffic-fatalities/accidents). Their [data dictionary](https://crashstats.nhtsa.dot.gov/Api/Public/ViewPublication/812315) is also really helpful for understanding the data.

Comment: The information and data dictionary are very helpful.  Just to clarify, this information is only for fatal accidents?

Comment: That's correct. There are about 30,000 fatal accidents per year in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link below, and you can also search by keyword in data.world for other related data. If you're interested in collaborating with other users on this or other datasets, you can request an invite to contribute in the "Contributors" tab of the dataset. Hope this helps!

https://data.world/transportation/2015-traffic-fatalities